# React Dom Outlet Route Confusion. Nest 3 Part Page Into one Route. React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having a hard time understanding how the routes and outlets work in react. My problem is this.

If I have a route that should load 3 parts.
-Top Menu
-Side Menu
-Center Content

But the center content is contained in the div thats wrapped by the "Side Menu" how do I wrap another element that will be changing inside of a previous component. My goal is to use the first 2 in all of the routes and based on the route the center content will change.

This is what it should look like

```
<div id="layoutSideNav">
 <div id="layoutsidenav_nav"></div>
 <div id="layoutSidenav_content"></div>
</div>
```

But for some reason all I can get is this

```
<div id="layoutSideNav">
  <div id="layoutsidenav_nav"></div>
</div>
<div id="layoutSidenav_content"></div>
```

My react looks like this.

3 Components

1. Contains the top nav
2. contains the side nav
3. contains body elements that will change.

App()

```
<Route
  path='/admin-dashboard'
  element={
    <>
      <AdminNavigation />
      <AdminNavigationLeft />
      <AdminDashBoardHome />
    </>
  }
>
```

If I add `<Outlet/>` before the closing div in "layoutSideNav" component. nothing happens. If I remove the outlets from all components the `app()` looks the same. The top nav and side nave display correclty, but the center content is wonky.

I feel like routes is so much more abstract than I'm used to so maybe I'm just not thinking about it logically. Thank you so much for your help!

I tried using `<Outlet/>` to adjust how where the third component content displayed.

I've added my full code below for review.

```
const AdminNavigation = () =>{

    const toggleSideMenu = event => {
        // ️ toggle class on click
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.toggle('sb-sidenav-toggled');
      };


return (
<Fragment>
<nav className="sb-topnav navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">

            <a className="navbar-brand ps-3" href="index.html">Woodmoore Improvement</a>

            <button className="btn btn-link btn-sm order-1 order-lg-0 me-4 me-lg-0" onClick={toggleSideMenu} id="sidebarToggle" href="#!"><i className="fas fa-bars"></i></button>

            <form className="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
                <div className="input-group">
                    <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for..." aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" id="btnNavbarSearch" type="button"><i className="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto ms-md-0 me-3 me-lg-4">
                <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i className="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i></a>
                    <ul className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#!">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><hr className="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                        <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#!">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

</Fragment>



)



}


export default AdminNavigation;
```

```
const AdminDashBoardHome = () => {


    return(
        <Fragment>

<div id='layoutSidenav_content'>
    <main>
        <div className='container-fluid px-4'>
            <h1 className='mt-4'>HOA Member Manager</h1>
            <ol className='breadcrumb mb-4'>
                <li className='breadcrumb-item active'>Member Map</li>
            </ol>
            <div className='row'>
                
                <div className='col-lg-12'>
                
                    
                <div className='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9'>
<div id='map_canvas' className='embed-responsive-item pb-4' >
                    

    </div>
    </div>

</div>
                            
    </div>
    <div className='row'>
        
        
    </div>
    <div className='card mb-4'>
        <div className='card-header'>
            <i className='fas fa-table me-1'></i>
            Member Lookup
        </div>
        <MemberDataList/>
    </div>
</div>
</main>
<footer className='py-4 bg-light mt-auto'>
<div className='container-fluid px-4'>
    <div className='d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between small'>
        <div className='text-muted'>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2022</div>
        <div>
            <a href='#'>Privacy Policy</a>
            &middot;
            <a href='#'>Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</footer>
</div>
            
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default AdminDashBoardHome;
```

```
const AdminNavigationLeft = () => {

document.body.classList.add('sb-nav-fixed');






return(
<Fragment>

<div id="layoutSidenav">
<Outlet/>
            <div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
                <nav className="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-dark" id="sidenavAccordion">
                    <div className="sb-sidenav-menu">
                        <div className="nav">
                            <div className="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>
                            <a className="nav-link" href="index.html">
                                <div className="sb-nav-link-icon"><i className="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>
                                Dashboard
                            </a>
                            <div className="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Interface</div>
                            <a className="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseLayouts" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseLayouts">
                                <div className="sb-nav-link-icon"><i className="fas fa-columns"></i></div>
                                Layouts
                                <div className="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i className="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                            </a>
                            <div className="collapse" id="collapseLayouts" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordion">
                                <nav className="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                                    <a className="nav-link" href="layout-static.html">Static Navigation</a>
                                    <a className="nav-link" href="layout-sidenav-light.html">Light Sidenav</a>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <a className="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsePages" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsePages">
                                <div className="sb-nav-link-icon"><i className="fas fa-book-open"></i></div>
                                Admin Management
                                <div className="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i className="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                            </a>
                            <div className="collapse" id="collapsePages" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordion">
                                <nav className="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav accordion" id="sidenavAccordionPages">
                                <a className="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#pagesCollapseAuth" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pagesCollapseAuth">
                                    Manage Users
                                </a>
                                <a className="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#pagesCollapseAuth" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pagesCollapseAuth">
                                    Create New
                                </a>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="sb-sidenav-footer">
                        <div className="small">Logged in as:</div>
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
</Fragment>



    )



}




export default AdminNavigationLeft;
```

Comment: Where do you want the routes to have their `element` rendered, the `<div id="layoutSidenav_content"></div>` element? Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] of the components you are trying to use?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that without posting a ton of styling code. Basically <AdminDashBoardHome /> needs to display inside of a div in <AdminNavigationLeft /> because the content inside <AdminDashBoardHome/> will change with the route, but the top and left menu will stay the same. Thank you

Comment: No, I don't think we need to see any CSS, just the component code for `AdminNavigation`, `AdminNavigationLeft`, and `AdminDashBoardHome`.

Comment: I've updated it with all the code

Answer (score 0):

If the following is what you intend to be rendered:

```
<div id="layoutSideNav">
  <div id="layoutsidenav_nav"></div>
  <div id="layoutSidenav_content"></div>
</div>
```

Then I suspect you want the routed content to be rendered in the `layoutSidenav_content` div. Something like the following:

```
<div id="layoutSideNav">
  <div id="layoutsidenav_nav">
    ... navbar content ...
  </div>
  <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
    ... routed content ...
  </div>
</div>
```

In other words, the above snippet describes a layout component, the routed content is the logical place for an `Outlet` component wrapping nested routes to output their `element` content into. The route may look like:

```
const AdminLayout = () => (
  <>
    <AdminNavigation />
    <div id="layoutsidenav">
      <div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
        <AdminNavigationLeft />
      </div>
      <div id="layoutsidenav_content">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
);
```

```
<Route
  path='/admin-dashboard'
  element={<AdminLayout />}
>
  <Route index element={<AdminDashBoardHome />} />
  ... other admin routes
</Route>
```

```
const AdminNavigationLeft = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add('sb-nav-fixed');
  }, []);

  return (
    <nav className="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-dark" id="sidenavAccordion">
      <div className="sb-sidenav-menu">
        ...
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

```
const AdminDashBoardHome = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <main>
        ...
      </main>
      <footer className='py-4 bg-light mt-auto'>
        ...
      </footer>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ive been researching this for a few days now and I solved it using this method.

 <Route path='/admin-dashboard' element={<><AdminNavigation /><AdminNavigationLeft><AdminDashBoardHome/></AdminNavigationLeft></>}>


And passing the prop.child to AdminNavigationLeft

Comment: @Karekin_FPV That's a possible solution if you don't need to reuse any of the navbar or sidebar as common ui.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to understand why that would matter though, because even if I create new routes and place content in the child it will then display into the prop.child though? Correct?

Comment: @Chris_S It would, but then you wouldn't really be routing to any specific content. Layout routes and the `Outlet` are a way to share common UI and "inject" the matched route's content into the container you want. It's a way to reduce code duplication and make your code more DRY if you needed to render more sub-routes with the same header/sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question.

You need to run the props through the component you're trying to display. The solution should be like this.

```
App()
 <Route path='/admin-dashboard' element={<><AdminNavigation /><AdminNavigationLeft><AdminDashBoardHome/></AdminNavigationLeft></>}>

AdminDashLeft()
const AdminNavigationLeft = (props) => {
 {props.children} // This is where the child component should display
}
```